# Can I use the Adapter design pattern to simplify lists of interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, interface, architecture

I have an application that makes use of two different interfaces that define one method each. The method name and returned result is the same, but the input parameters differ.

Examples:

```
//Interface A
public interface IPropertyTypifier
{
    IEnumerable<ProbabilityScore> CalculateProbabilities(
        AccessAddress accessAddress,
        AddressKey targetKey);
}

//Interface B
public interface INameTypifier
{
    IEnumerable<ProbabilityScore> CalculateProbabilities(string name);
}
```

I have several classes that implement this interface, which are then added to another class that contains a list of these as such:

```
public class TypificationService
{
    public IEnumerable<IPropertyTypifier> PropertyTypifiers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<INameTypifier> NameTypifiers { get; set; }

    TypificationResult Typify(AccessAddress accessAddress, AddressKey targetKey, string name)
    {
        // For each property typifier get result here

        // For each name typifier get result here

        // Return result
    }
}
```

Does it make sense here to use Adapter to instead create an interface that allows me to keep a single list of typifiers? Or is this design already flawed as it is?

Comment: To me it looks more like a case for method overloading than to have two different classes just for that. Just a thought!

Answer (score 0):

If that's all the functionality that you need, rather than creating two different interfaces, I would create an interface "ProbabilityCalculator" and overload CalculateProbabilities method.

```
interface IProbabilityCalculator
{
    IEnumerable<ProbabilityScore> CalculateProbabilities(string name);
    IEnumerable<ProbabilityScore> CalculateProbabilities(AccessAddress accessAddress, AddressKey targetKey);
}
```